# Doxygen for web services?

Tags: c++, rest, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have a (semi)RESTful web service that I'm working on written in c++.  We use doxygen to document our classes/functions/etc.  Is there an easy way to use doxygen to document web services, is there another tool I could use, or am I better off just creating a document myself?

Comment: Your code is written in C++. Doxygen is an excellent tool for creating docs for C++ code. What special features do you need to document the code of a web service, I mean, in addition to what is needed to document regular C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of exposing Web service interfaces is by using a **[WADL doccument](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/)**.
So stick to that instead of using Doxygen for it. You can use any **[WADL editors](http://wiki.netbeans.org/WadlVisualDesigner)** available to create an WADL.

Comment: AFAIK WSDL is for SOAP. We are talking about REST here...

Comment: @kol: Ah, Typo, WADL it is not WSDL.

Comment: Sorry, I just read that WSDL can also be applied to document REST services :) http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/documenting-rest-services-wsdl-and-wadl.html